# What are the abilities, sizes, and appearance of tyrannosaur rex?

Tags: palaeontology

Size 
height 15-20ft tall
weight 7-9tons
length 40-42ft long

did the flim of jurassic park had some corrections of the reality I beilve there many things they gotten right on the trex

Comment: you really need to show some research of your own, you also need to be more specific about what you are asking, Are you just asking what is wrong with the ones in jurassic park?

Comment: I’m asking were the Trex in Jurassic Park flims were indeed right of their appearance size and abilities

Comment: You may want to change the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The jurassic park rex is probably the best one ever put on film. the hands and skin are the biggest errors everything else is pretty good asinde from a few minor things.

It should probably be feathered but that is relatively recent discovery so they can be forgiven , how the feathers were distributed is anyone's guess. the weight estimates range from 5-9 tons with reality likey somewhere in between, 7-tons is a safe estimate for the largest ones.

The arms are a little too big and the finger position is all wrong. The fingers are held laterally (palms toward the midline) like a birds wing and with a lot less flex in the fingers and the arms would have been closer together. the production crew even admits they changed the arms to make it more intimidating.

They did make the rear portion of the head too narrow, it spreads out more with wide "cheeks"(jugal) improving the binocular vision and increasing the size of the jaw muscles. they did improve this in more recent movies. The base of the tail might be a little skinny too but that is nitpicking.

for scale and measurements use a scientific skeletal drawing like this. 
[image]

[image]

As for behavior the only seeing movement thing is total fiction, but even the movie make it clear this is due to the genetic reconstruction not natural so no points lost. T-rex actually has a really good suite of senses with better hearing and smell than many other dinosaurs and binocular vision to boot. They would have head better vision than a human and a sense of smell comparable to a modern bloodhound. Hearing would have been good for a dinosaur but still inferior to a modern mammal.

The bite force we see on screen is light and dainty compared to what the animal could actually do, T-rex has the most powerful bite of any animal known.

40 mph is within the highest estimates of its speed but not unbelievable, 25-30 is more likely. T-rex does have some derived adaptations for speed (elongated interlocking compressed metatarsals, transverse processes on the caudals,ect) and was probably the faster and/or more maneuverable than other large theropod and it may have been faster as an adolescent. [great lecture on T-rex anatomy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqkqkxYGNZc).

Vocalization is an issue t-rex probably could not roar but it could have honked like a goose, and when you scale up a honk to T-rex size it will still end up sounding roar like, the roar from the movie is not that bad.

I am sure someone who has watched the movies more recently can recall a few other errors.

Comment: tyrannosaur rex roar could be possible since these dinosaurs were non avian birds they could roar. trex height 15-20ft tall so the height is correct and speed mostly 20mph